# Relational Database on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started using rails,

I have a model generated with a set of 3 attributes, and I have controllers and views written for it, now I need another database or a model which has 4 attributes, where the second and the third attributes of the new model have to be linked to the 2 attributes in the original database, how do I create or generate this model?

Primary database (Books)

BookID, Bookname , no.of.books

Secondary database  (Usage)
Customername, Bookname , noofbooks_rented.

The changes have to reflect on the original database.
Thanks for the help in advance..

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: models and databases are different because models reffer to tables in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your books model

```
class BooK < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer

def count_books
  //count all books on a particular user
end

end
```

In your customer model

```
class Customer <ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
end
```

Comment: actually there is no need for `count_books`, just do `customer.books.count`

Comment: your right ismaelga. it's just to make it neat when you get books count in an instanced object.